# DynamoDB Stream Remains After Table Dropped/Deleted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

If I drop a DynamoDB table with a stream, the table goes away, but I can still see the stream for several days:

[image]

Why is that? How can I delete those unused streams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation for DynamoDB delete-table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/delete-table.html):

> If you have DynamoDB Streams enabled on the table, then the corresponding stream on that table goes into the DISABLED state, and the stream is automatically deleted after 24 hours.

Comment: That one stream (5/1) is over 24 hours old. I guess it just eventually cleans itself up.